Excel is viewing dates in different formats. How do we fix it?
So we are working with a SAP system. We extract files from SAP and then work with it (Analysis) in MS Excel. After extracting a certain dataset, Excel views dates differently all of a sudden.
For example:
05/01/2024     This is viewed by Excel as January 05, 2024
05/16/2024     Excel does not view this as a date at all since it views dates in dd/mm/yyyy format only.
We have tries applying custom date formats to no avail. We've set English (United States) as the preferred language too and it still does not work.
Please help us how to solve this issue. I'd appreciate any input from you guys, thank you very much in advance.

I assume, your system date format is dd/mm/yyyy. So, 05/01/2024 here 1 is month which is January. But 05/16/2024, here 16 treating as month which is false and Excel treating it as just text. Use DATE() function with LEFT/RIGHT/MID to convert this text to pure date values.

As far I know you can set the date formatting in SAP itself, have you tried to check the profile button and change in language and date settings? I usually import with DD.MM.YYYY format, later on in excel, just use text to columns to fix !

Are you using Power Query to get that data in?

Used this then did Text to Columns to force excel to read my dates in the way my computer displayed the dates. Thank you very much and hope to talk to you again soon!

Glad your issue is sorted but I would like to know if you are using Power Query to get that data in?

Excel uses the date-time format set on the Windows Region Settings.
Go to start and type "set regional format"
Click on "Set regional format" menu item.
Select English (United States) from the Regional format dropdown list.
This should set the mm/dd/yyyy format and Excel will accept 05/16/2024.
